# Where are all the people with a day-related event located in Pokemon Sun and Moon demo?

Tags: pokemon-sm-demo

I'm playing Pokemon Sun&Moon Demo.
Along with the main guided experience, there are also citizens throughout the city who seem to suggest that you can return on certain days after you start playing to participate in additional events.

Here's the list of the people I've found so far, and how many days they ask you to wait (starting from release date, October 18):

- A guy outside the Pokecenter (1 day, 19th October)
- A girl waiting for a date in the western corner of the city, near the trees (5 days, 23rd October)
- A guy waiting for his Pikachu's birthday in the City Hall (12 days, 30th October)
- A policeman at the dock, waiting for a "strange meeting" (18 days, 5th November)
- A nervous girl waiting for the ferry (24 days, 11th November)

Have I found them all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All of the events in pokémon Sun & Moon demo?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288921/all-of-the-events-in-pok%c3%a9mon-sun-moon-demo)

Comment: @Michaellogg my question is 3 days older, so how can it be a duplicate?

Comment: I flagged them both as duplicates of each other. I didn't know which one to consider better, so I thought I'd let them fight it out. Regarding age: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/on-ending-chronological-oppression-with-respect-to-the-matter-of-question-duplic

Comment: @Michaellogg Ok, I read that post. Imho both question are well asked. *Karlyr* just haven't found this question and simply posted another similar one (with a new different tag), so I'm still convinced that the other one is the dupe.

Comment: This one should definitely be the dupe.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Only after the latest edit. If I edit my question adding the rewards part the other one becomes a dupe again. And then?

Comment: I mean that the question is flawed to begin with. Rather than asking "I found these, is that all?", it should be "What are all of the events?"

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer The title already follows your suggestion, the only "flaw" is that my question answers itself and I didn't know that when I asked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possibly two other people that do something:

- the man outside the Tourist Centre mentions age 11 as a rite of passage, hinting that 11 days will lead to something maybe.
- the barista inside the Pokémon Centre says the owner will be back "in about a month".

source:
http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-10-17-pokemon-sun-and-moon-demo-guide-how-to-unlock-ash-greninja-in-the-full-game

For the rest your list seems to be complete.

Comment: That "about a month" could mean "when the game is released". Is the same as the guy at the Pokemarket, imho.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 5 citizens with a day-related event, and they are listed above.

For the sake of curiosity, I'm meeting those people and here are the results:

- *1 day after download* (October 19): The boy outside the Pokecenter gives you 10 *Pretty Wings*, useless item, but he also said that if you find the others something interesting will happen.
- *5 days after download* (October 23): The "guy" who saved the girl is a Machamp. No item received.
- *12 days after download* (October 30): The guy celebrating his Pikachu's birthday in the City Hall gives you a *Balm Mushroom*.
- *18 days after download* (November 5): Only an in-game event.
- *24 days after download* (November 11): The reward is a *Comet Shard*.

The dates listed in parentheses are the dates you'll need to log in on **assuming you downloaded the demo when it released on October 18th**.

Source [here](https://nowloading.co/p/ash-greninja-isnt-only-secret-reward-you-can-get-from-sun-and-moon-demo/4129097).