# All of the events and rewards in pokémon Sun & Moon demo?

Tags: pokemon-sm-demo

After completing the main "story" of the demo (ending when you defeat the Skull Sister), I noticed a guy that was talking about meeting him the day after and another saying in 5 days, how many are there?

And, if datamined somewhere, what do they give for the main game?

Comment: Voting to reopen because of the added addition of the Rewards related to each events. Which isn't mentionned complete in the said post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These events are related to the first time you connected. They will occur on the exact date that they say they will. (The guy outside the pokémon center warns you about this.) Don't miss them if you want these bonuses.

- A guy next to the pokémon center scheduling for 1 day after your first connection. (Reward : 10 pretty wings)
- A woman in the far left corner of the town scheduling for 5 days after your first connection. (Reward : An in game event)
- A pokéfan and his buddy pikachu in the city hall scheduling for 12 days after your first connection. (Reward : Balm Mushroom)
- A police agent on the pier scheduling for 18 days after your first connection. (Reward : An in game event)
- A girl in the ferry terminal scheduling for 24 days after your first connection. (Reward : Comet Shard)

http://bgr.com/2016/10/19/pokemon-sun-moon-demo-secret-rewards/

P.S. You also get a Greninja from completing the story line.

Comment: In case anyone was still wondering, the Cafe is still closed after a month.